# mongo db lookup query on array into single result

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework, lookup

I'm executing a lookup query using the $unwind in order to find all the array elements results out of an array field of one collection joined with another collection. I use the below query:

```
db.getCollection('Products').aggregate([{$unwind:"$SupplierOffers"},{$lookup:{from:"Offers", localField:"SupplierOffers",foreignField:"_id", as:"Producttypes"}},
{$project:{"Producttypes.offeringType":1, _id:1}}])
```

The actual results are

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bfe8978192b5c14e8d88ba7"),
    "Producttypes" : [ 
        {
            "offeringType" : "package A"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bfe8978192b5c14e8d88ba7"),
    "Producttypes" : [ 
        {
            "offeringType" : "package B"
        }
    ]
}
```

because of the unwind annotation, is it possible i have a result like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bfe8978192b5c14e8d88ba7"),
    "Producttypes" : [ 
        {
            "offeringType" : ["package A","package B"]
        }
    ]
}
```

i suppose this refers to group or it is not possible due to unwind?I need this this way, so I can further handle it into meteor.

Comment: Your expected output is not a valid JSON. Try to fix it

Comment: why do you first $unwind the SupplierOffers?  It's a scalar array so you can just do a $lookup based on that.  The result will be an array then, you won't need to do a $group after.

Comment: also, you can't just $group after $lookup here because you'll end up with array of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that you're looking for [group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

Try adding this to your pipeline

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: '_id',
    offeringType: { $addToSet: '$Producttypes.offeringType' }
  }
}
```

**Edit:** here's the final query from the comments, for posterity:

```
db.getCollection("Products").aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$SupplierOffers"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Offers",
      localField: "SupplierOffers",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "Producttypes"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      offeringType: { $addToSet: "$Producttypes.offeringType" }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { _id: 1 } }
]);
```

Comment: thanks @elhil , after some careful reading about https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group the final query is: `db.getCollection('Products').aggregate([
{
    $unwind:"$SupplierOffers"
},
{
    $lookup:
    {from:"Offers", 
    localField:"SupplierOffers",
    foreignField:"_id",
    as:"Producttypes"
 }},
    {
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    offeringType: { $addToSet: '$Producttypes.offeringType' }
  }
},
{ $sort : { _id : 1} }
 ])`

Comment: Glad I could help @user2829319, thanks for giving us the final result :)

Comment: This won't give you the array of offering types, it will give you an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This turns out to be more straight forward if you don't first `$unwind` the original documents.  `$lookup` is able to look up directly from an array of "foreign keys" and the result will then be an array already, avoiding the need to have another `$unwind` and `$group` after.

```
db.getCollection('Products').aggregate([
    { $lookup: {
        from:"Offers",        
        localField:"SupplierOffers", 
        foreignField:"_id", 
        as:"Producttypes" 
    }}
])
```

Optionally if you want to transform the Producttypes to just have the offeringType field in it you can add `{ $addFields: {Producttypes: '$Producttypes.offeringType' } } }`

Answer (score 0):

I agree the aggregation is great and essential functionality,
but sometimes it makes us hard to control small but specific changes.

So I recommend in Meteor.js that 'this.added' something like below could be one of the good solution without aggregation.

```
# Writing in Coffeescript
Meteor.publish 'pubName' ->
  cursor = Products.find()
  cursor.forEach (product) => #fat arrow for this binding
    #Play anything with product and the other collection's data
    product.Producttypes = Offers.findOne(_id: product.SupplierOffers)
    this.added('pubName', product._id, product) #The data binded to Products could be use in client
  return [
    cursor
    OtherCollection.find() #other collections to subscribe
  ]
```

Hope to this could be helpful.